Disable switching fullscreen(alt+enter) in a Direct3D 11
As written in the title, how?
I thought that DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH in DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC::flags was responsible about this, but even when I set DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC::flags to 0, the switching doesn't disable.

Use IDXGIFactory::MakeWindowAssociation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-idxgifactory-makewindowassociation with DXGI_MWA_NO_WINDOW_CHANGES

Actually I think you want DXGI_MWA_NO_ALT_ENTER

@simon-mourier Worked, but when I press Alt+Enter, my system (Windows 10) emits a default beep sound.

Yes, it was DXGI_MWA_NO_ALT_ENTER, have you tried this one?

@simon-mourier Whether it's DXGI_MWA_NO_WINDOW_CHANGES or DXGI_MWA_NO_ALT_ENTER, the result is the same "Worked, but when I press Alt+Enter, my system (Windows 10) emits a default beep sound.".

By default, any ALT+somekey press will trigger a sound if not handled, are you speaking about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662192/disable-messagebeep-on-invalid-syskeypress

@simon-mourier Yes, and this solve the problem, thanks.

According to @Simon Mourier, I should have used IDXGIFactory::MakeWindowAssociation. And to disable MessageBeep, I should have used WM_MENUCHAR and returned MNC_CLOSE << 16 when it occurs.
